# Can I run my flutter app on a physical android device 5.1 lollipop

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

1.I'm using android 9 sdk for coding my app on flutter, Can I run my app on a physical android device with version  5.1 lollipop?

2.How do I know the android version my app supports? I'm using flutter on Vscode

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `build.gradle` inside Android folder, there should be a `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` with the values of the minimum Android supported version and the target version

Comment: Lollipop is the sdk version 22, if your minSdkVersion is lower than that then it should support it. Usually flutter has support from version 16(Android jellybean) https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers